# Android programming[ the new boston tutorial no 27]

Tags: android

I've been learning android programming from the new boston tutorials, and I'm on tutorial #27 and I've gotten stuck.

When I try to open the startplay activity it doesn't open. The program closes saying that the app stopped responding.

I've tried ALL the tweaks possible and it STILL doesn't work.

I've been stuck on this since the past two days/

The `Manifest.xml` is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.thenewboston"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".StartingPoint"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.thenewboston.STARTINGPOINT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <activity
       android:name=".Menu"
       android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.example.thenewboston.MENU" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       </intent-filter>
       </activity>  

        <activity
       android:name=".TextpLay"
       android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.example.thenewboston.Textplay" />
        </intent-filter>
       </activity>  

</application>

</manifest>
```

The `menu` is :

```
package com.example.thenewboston;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity{

    String classes[]= {"StartingPoint","Textplay","example2","example3","example4","example5","example6"};

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));


        }

        @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
            String cheese=classes[position];
            try{
            Class<?> ourClass= Class.forName("com.example.thenewboston."+ cheese);
            Intent ourIntent= new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
            startActivity(ourIntent);
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

}
```

the stack trace or the logcat output is:

```
07-15 19:04:56.508: W/dalvikvm(572): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
07-15 19:04:56.558: E/AndroidRuntime(572): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 19:04:56.558: E/AndroidRuntime(572): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.thenewboston/com.example.thenewboston.Textplay}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
07-15 19:04:56.558: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1508)
07-15 19:04:56.558: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
07-15 19:04:56.558: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
07-15 19:04:56.558: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
07-15 19:04:56.558: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at com.example.thenewboston.Menu.onListItemClick(Menu.java:30)
07-15 19:04:56.558: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
07-15 19:04:56.558: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
07-15 19:04:56.558: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)
07-15 19:04:56.558: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)
07-15 19:04:56.558: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)
07-15 19:04:56.558: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-15 19:04:56.558: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-15 19:04:56.558: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-15 19:04:56.558: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
07-15 19:04:56.558: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 19:04:56.558: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-15 19:04:56.558: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-15 19:04:56.558: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-15 19:04:56.558: E/AndroidRuntime(572):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to be able to help you, please include the exception stacktrace. Also, Please try to avoid using capslocks.

Comment: Welcome to programming! It's not easy.

Comment: yeah included it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the logcat output, you'll notice this line:

```
07-15 19:04:56.558: E/AndroidRuntime(572): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.thenewboston/com.example.thenewboston.Textplay}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

This indicates it thinks you haven't added the Textplay activity to your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Looking at your posted AndroidManifest, it looks like you put in `TextpLay` instead of `Textplay`

```
   <activity
   android:name=".TextpLay"
   android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Comment: I'll just go kill myself now.

Comment: One more qucikk question,
If i build an app targetting,lets suppose, 4.0, will it work on a fone opearting on a higher version of android like 4.4 or smthng?